# Is it true that if $\phi :G \rightarrow G $ defined by $ \phi(x)=x^{4}$ is a homomorphism, then $G$ is abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Is it true that if $\phi :G \rightarrow G $ defined by $ \phi(x)=x^{4}$ is a homomorphism, then $G$ is abelian?

By the property of homomorphisms we see that $\forall x,y \in G $ we have

$$\begin{align}
\phi(xy) = \phi(x)\phi(y) &\Rightarrow (xy)^4 = x^4 y^4 \\
&\Rightarrow (yx)^3=x^3y^3.
\end{align}$$

I couldn't find of a way to get $xy=yx$ from this.

I tried to find a counter-example by considering small non-abelian groups such as $D_3$ and $S_4$ however for those, there were always elements such that $\phi(xy) \neq \phi(x)\phi(y)$

Comment: Am I missing something? $\phi(xy) = \phi(x)\phi(y)$ would imply $(xy)^2 = x^2 y^2$ and thus $xyxy = xxyy$ and so $yx = xy$.

Comment: Ah I wrote the title wrong, it's supposed to be $\phi(x) = x^4 $, it's edited now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the dihedral group $D_4$ acting on four elements, the fourth power of any element is the identity. And sending each element to the identity is always a homomorphism, but $D_4$ is not abelian.

Comment: and $D_4$ is not Abelian

Comment: This makes sense, but what does "acting on four elements" mean?

Comment: @Shree Any permutation group acts on some set of elements. For instance, the full symmetric group $S_4$, the alternating group $A_4$, the dihedral group $D_4$ and the cyclic group $C_4$ all act on a set of _four_ elements. Usually, $D_4$ is visualised as the symmetry group of a square, acting on the **four corners** by rotation and mirroring.